# Docker Desktop for Windows - Single Command window

Tags: docker, windows-10

I installed Docker for Windows and everything appears to be working **except** that when I open a command window to execute a Docker command, something like `docker image list`, the Docker app will open a second command window, execute the command and then close the second window, I can not review the output since the second window closes so quickly. Is there a way to get the Docker command output in the first window or to hold the second window open long enough to see the output?

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it by running the cmd shell with admin privileges.

Answer (score 1):

I actually am facing the same issue.
It works perfectly inside Git Bash but exhibits the spawning behavior on cmd prompt, Powershell, as well as git cmd.

And I tried switching between Linux and Windows containers, but the problem persists.

I guess sticking with Git bash seems like the way for now.

---

UPDATE: 26th July 2020

I found a workaround to the issue at hand.
By going to the "Learn" option in Docker Desktop, it opens a tutorial window with a PowerShell window.
That Powershell can be used to execute all Docker commands without the pop-up issue.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

What terminal are you running the command in? Mine performs normally on Windows using Powershell.

Comment: I tried the big 3, Powershell, a normal dos command prompt and a command prompt with admin privileges. All three behave the same, they open a new window, title is something like Docker Command, the command executes and the second window closes when the Docker command completes.

Comment: Second question, when you installed Docker, did you choose to have Windows containers, or Linux containers? I'm not entirely positive as I've always used Linux containers, but if you chose Windows that might be why.

[docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/] sounds like what you're experiencing.

Comment: I don't recall, whatever the default was but that sounds promising. Also, I tried running the Docker commands in Git Bash and they are displaying correctly there.

Comment: It sounds like older versions of git on Windows used Cygwin which is a Linux like environment so if the above from the documentation is holding true, that might explain why its working there. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: No luck, it's already set to Linux, I'll mess around with switching between Linux and Windows containers and see if that help. At least it work in Git Bash for windows so I can use it without spinning up a VM just for this.